# How to return two objects (including one list) in JSON with WCF

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf, list

I am trying to resolve my issue.

This is my Service Contract (IService1.vb)

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/GetBooks")> _
Function GetBooks() As List(Of Book)

<DataContract()> _
Class Book
    Public Property bookchapter() As List(Of Chapter)
        Get
            Return m_bookchapter
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Chapter))
            m_bookchapter = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_bookchapter As List(Of Chapter)

    Public Property success() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_success
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_success = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_success As Integer
End Class

<DataContract()> _
Class Chapter
    Public Property description() As String
        Get
            Return m_description
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_description = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_description As String
End Class
```

This is my Service (Service1.vb)

```
Public Function GetBooks() As List(Of IGPService.Book) Implements IGPService.GetBooks
    Dim books As New List(Of IGPService.Book)

    Dim newBook As IGPService.Book = New IGPService.Book

    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        Dim newchapter As IGPService.Chapter = New IGPService.Chapter
        newchapter.description = "Chapter1"
        newBook.bookchapter.Add(newchapter)
    Next

    newBook.success = 1

    books.Add(newBook)

    Return books
End Function
```

When I call GetBooks, I get the following error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. See server
>   logs for more details.

I don't know what is wrong here. I couldn't find anything in the Windows EventLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a New() Contructor to the Book Class and now it works. But i don't know why!

```
Class Book
    Public Property bookchapter() As List(Of Chapter)
        Get
            Return m_bookchapter
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Chapter))
            m_bookchapter = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_bookchapter As List(Of Chapter)

    Public Property success() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_success
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_success = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_success As Integer

        **Public Sub New()
            bookchapter = New List(Of Chapter)
        End Sub**
End Class
```

I want to understand why this is. Can somebody explain me the difference with and without New()!

Comment: There was no contructor for the List.